# Error `make` erlang after downloading latest binary

Tags: linux, cmake, erlang, erlang-otp

I ran ./configure

I had a couple errors that documentation couldn't be built because there was no java compiler. I didn't think that was related so I went ahead with `make`:

What is `Error 4`?

```
oot@marble-pyramid-1:~/download/otp_src_20.0# make
 MAKE   depend
make[1]: Entering directory `/root/download/otp_src_20.0/erts/emulator'
 MAKE   generate
make[2]: Entering directory `/root/download/otp_src_20.0/erts/emulator'
 GEN    x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/gen_git_version.mk
 GEN    x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/OPCODES-GENERATED
 GEN    x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/TABLES-GENERATED
 GEN    x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_alloc_types.h
 GEN    x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/erl_version.h
 GEN    x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/driver_tab.c
 GEN    x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/GENERATED
 GEN    x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/preload.c
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/download/otp_src_20.0/erts/emulator'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/download/otp_src_20.0/erts/emulator'
make[1]: Entering directory `/root/download/otp_src_20.0/erts/emulator'
 MAKE   depend
make[2]: Entering directory `/root/download/otp_src_20.0/erts/emulator'
 GEN    x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/depend.mk
make[3]: Entering directory `/root/download/otp_src_20.0/erts/lib_src'
 MAKE   depend
make[4]: Entering directory `/root/download/otp_src_20.0/erts/lib_src'
 GEN    obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/depend.mk
make[4]: Leaving directory `/root/download/otp_src_20.0/erts/lib_src'
make[4]: Entering directory `/root/download/otp_src_20.0/erts/lib_src'
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `depend'.
make[4]: Leaving directory `/root/download/otp_src_20.0/erts/lib_src'
make[3]: Leaving directory `/root/download/otp_src_20.0/erts/lib_src'
 GEN    x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/gen_git_version.mk
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/download/otp_src_20.0/erts/emulator'
make[2]: Entering directory `/root/download/otp_src_20.0/erts/emulator'
 GEN    x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/gen_git_version.mk
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `depend'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/download/otp_src_20.0/erts/emulator'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/download/otp_src_20.0/erts/emulator'
make[1]: Entering directory `/root/download/otp_src_20.0/erts/lib_src'
 MAKE   depend
make[2]: Entering directory `/root/download/otp_src_20.0/erts/lib_src'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `depend'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/download/otp_src_20.0/erts/lib_src'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/download/otp_src_20.0/erts/lib_src'
 MAKE   emulator
make[1]: Entering directory `/root/download/otp_src_20.0/erts'
make[2]: Entering directory `/root/download/otp_src_20.0/erts'
make[3]: Entering directory `/root/download/otp_src_20.0/erts/emulator'
 MAKE   opt
make[4]: Entering directory `/root/download/otp_src_20.0/erts/emulator'
 GEN    x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/gen_git_version.mk
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_main.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/preload.o
 EMU_CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/beam_emu.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/beam_opcodes.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/beam_load.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/beam_bif_load.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/beam_debug.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/beam_bp.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/beam_catches.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/code_ix.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/beam_ranges.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_alloc.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_mtrace.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_alloc_util.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_goodfit_alloc.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_bestfit_alloc.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_afit_alloc.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_instrument.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_init.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_atom_table.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_bif_table.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_bif_ddll.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_bif_guard.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_bif_info.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_bif_op.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_bif_os.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_bif_lists.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_bif_trace.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_bif_unique.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_bif_wrap.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_nfunc_sched.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_guard_bifs.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_dirty_bif_wrap.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_trace.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/copy.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/utils.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/bif.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/io.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_printf_term.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_debug.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_md5.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_message.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_process.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_process_dict.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_process_lock.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_port_task.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_arith.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/time.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_time_sup.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/external.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/dist.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/binary.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_db.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_db_util.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_db_hash.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_db_tree.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_thr_progress.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/big.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/hash.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/index.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/atom.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/module.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/export.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/register.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/break.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_async.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_lock_check.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_gc.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_lock_count.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_posix_str.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_bits.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_math.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_fun.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_bif_port.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_term.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_node_tables.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_monitors.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_process_dump.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_hl_timer.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_cpu_topology.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_drv_thread.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_bif_chksum.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_bif_re.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_unicode.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/packet_parser.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/safe_hash.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_zlib.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_nif.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_bif_binary.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_ao_firstfit_alloc.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_thr_queue.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_sched_spec_pre_alloc.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_ptab.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_map.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_msacc.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/sys.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/sys_drivers.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/sys_uds.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/driver_tab.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/unix_efile.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/gzio.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/elib_memmove.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/sys_float.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/sys_time.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_poll.kp.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_check_io.kp.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_poll.nkp.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_check_io.nkp.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_mseg.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_mmap.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_unix_sys_ddll.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_mtrace_sys_wrap.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_sys_common_misc.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_os_monotonic_time_extender.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erlang_lttng.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/efile_drv.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/inet_drv.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/zlib_drv.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/ram_file_drv.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/ttsl_drv.o
 CC obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/smp/erl_tracer_nif.o
 CC /root/download/otp_src_20.0/erts/emulator/pcre/obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/pcre_latin_1_table.o
 CC /root/download/otp_src_20.0/erts/emulator/pcre/obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/pcre_compile.o
 CC /root/download/otp_src_20.0/erts/emulator/pcre/obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/pcre_config.o
 CC /root/download/otp_src_20.0/erts/emulator/pcre/obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/pcre_dfa_exec.o
 GEN    /root/download/otp_src_20.0/erts/emulator/pcre/pcre_exec_loop_break_cases.inc
 CC /root/download/otp_src_20.0/erts/emulator/pcre/obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/pcre_exec.o
gcc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.8/README.Bugs> for instructions.
make[4]: *** [/root/download/otp_src_20.0/erts/emulator/pcre/obj/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/opt/pcre_exec.o] Error 4
make[4]: Leaving directory `/root/download/otp_src_20.0/erts/emulator'
make[3]: *** [opt] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory `/root/download/otp_src_20.0/erts/emulator'
make[2]: *** [opt] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/download/otp_src_20.0/erts'
make[1]: *** [smp] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/root/download/otp_src_20.0/erts'
make: *** [emulator] Error 2
root@marble-pyramid-1:~/download/otp_src_20.0#
```

Comment: It says "Killed". That might be caused by the Linux OOM killer (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/39893846/320615). How much RAM does this system have? Is it possible to increase the RAM temporarily?

Comment: It looks like memory issue.How much RAM and swap space is there?

Comment: @Dogbert currently 512 MB. Will 1024MB be enough?

Comment: @quantumpotato Probably :) I've never tried compiling Erlang on a system with < 2GB RAM.

Comment: Thanks. I'm resizing to 2GB (digital ocean says it may take a while), I'll try again later

Answer (score 1):

Regarding Java's availability, that only affects whether the Java interface is available -- and it doesn't sound like you need that.

The rest is here: http://erlang.org/doc/installation_guide/INSTALL.html

As for memory, it looks like you have 4 jobs running. If you are using parallel make, (perhaps using `make -j4` or `make -j`?) that could be exploding your memory requirements. I would be shocked if you need more than 512MB to build vanilla Erlang. Try building with a single thread.